# Редактор выдает Allocation of incomplete type 'Test' в случае отдельных header и cpp файлов

Tags: c++, header, include

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include "Test.hpp"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



    Test test = new Test(1,3,4,5);

    std::vector<int> v = {};

    cout << "";
}
```

На месте new Test(1,3,4,5)   вылезает ошибка Allocation of incomplete type 'Test'

Test.hpp файл

```
#pragma once

#ifndef RO_TEST_HPP
#define RO_TEST_HPP


class Test;

template <typename T>
T sum(T t1, T t2){
    return t1 + t2;
}
```

Test.cpp файл

```
#include "Test.hpp"

class Test {

public:
    int a,b,c,d;

    Test(int a1, int b1, int c1, int d1){
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
        c = c1;
        d = d1;
    }

    virtual void add(){

    }

};
```

вроде header файл и cpp заинклюжены, в header - only стиле ошибки не возникает

Comment: *cpp заинклюжены* - cpp файл не заинклюжен, поэтому содержащееся в нем определение класса `Test` (после которого класс становится complete) не доступно

Comment: Определение класса `Test` должно находиться в заголовочном файле. В отдельный .cpp вы можете вынести реализацию (конструктор, функцию `add()`.

Comment: Выделение памяти для класса `Test` возвращает **указатель**, вы его присваиваете  объекту. надо так : `Test * test = new Test(1,3,4,5);` Предварительное объявление **типа** при `class Test;` не указывает никаких методов для него и размеров. см : `Определение класса Test должно находиться в заголовочном файле...`